# How to get data-id value onchange (textbox)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to get data-id input value onchange or oninput? Here is my html and js code. The output is: `123,abc`

Unable to get textbox value which I typed

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function activitiesServices(invId) {
      console.log($(invId).data('id'));
      
      $.ajax({
        url: "./tripdetails/Trip2.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
          inventoryId: $(invId).data('id')
        },
        success: function(dataResult) {
          $('#ajaxDiv').html(dataResult);
        }
      });
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="n_QWaitlistedS" name="n_QWaitlistedS" value="" data-id="123,abc" onchange="activitiesServices(this);">
  <div id="ajaxDiv" style="background-color:red"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're already getting the `data-id` output, as can be seen in the snippet I edited in to the question.. what's the problem?

Comment: I want textbox value as well when I typed

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/val

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Pass textbox value through another parameter!
        data:{
        inventoryId: $(invId).data("id"),
        **dataValue: value,**
        },